# Custom tick values disappearing on d3 bar plot

Tags: d3.js

My project is measuring signal power levels at discrete intervals and I am trying to represent that in a bar plot. Since the frequencies are discrete I am trying to set the tick values using an array, they work fine when I provide [1, 2] but act weird when i provide bigger values.

Below is the code, I am just trying with local data at the moment because I am new to D3.

```
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Width and height
            var w = 1000;
            var h = 500;
            var barPadding = 1;  // padding space to distinguish bars
            var axisSpace = 25;

            var dataset =[200,40];
            var tix = [55,57]

            // SCALES
            var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .domain([0, dataset.length])
                                .range([0,w]);
            var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){return d;})])
                                .range([0,h]);

            //AXES
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(xscale)// define simple axis function with scales
                            .orient("top")  // define the orientation of labels
                            .tickValues(tix);
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis(yscale);




            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h)


            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / dataset.length);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yscale(d);
               })
               .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return (yscale(d) - axisSpace);
               })
               .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 550) + ")";
               });


               // call axis function on svg element
               svg.append("g")  // append new group to save all axes
                    .attr("class", "axis")  // assign it a class so we can target it using CSS
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 477)") // 477 = h - axisSpace + 2
                    .call(xAxis); // call axis function

        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
.domain([0, dataset.length])
```

Sets your domain from 0 to 2.  Your ticks:

```
var tix = [55,57]
```

are not within this domain, so you get no ticks.

Perhaps you want:

```
.domain(tix)
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zjv0bTQVtdgukLRSNaer?p=preview).